How did Gloria get on Jeopardy?
In White Men Can't Jump (1992), Gloria has applied to be on the gameshow Jeopardy and is studying hard in anticipation of them calling her, but the call never comes. However eventually she gets to be on the show, apparently thanks to Sidney knowing Robert, who works for the studio where the show is made.
However, this guy is a security guard!

Nobody gets on my lot without a pass.


I'm a security guard, man, I take that shit seriously!

Surely he has no authority to decide who gets to appear as contestant! The conversation that follows seems to imply he'll allow her in the door, but presumably to appear on the show takes more than that! Later, when Gloria and Billy are talking it's revealed she has no idea that arrangements had been made, and someone actually called her to appear.
So how did Gloria get on the show, and what did it have to do with Robert? (OK maybe he had friends in high places, or could put in a good word, but this is never mentioned)

Because she knew every food that begins with the letter "Q".  :P

I'm assuming the security guard went and talked to a junior producer. "Hey, buddy, can you let my friend on. She's pretty smart and I owe her old man a favour"

@Valorum - the most plausible explanation to how he did it, but that makes that conversation really confusing!
